# TypeScript paths not working with ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register

Tags: typescript, ts-node

Please see this repo for minimal reproduction: https://github.com/ALeschinsky/ts-node

This doesn't work:

`ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --esm --experimentalSpecifierResolution=node src/ts-script2.ts`

The error I'm getting is:

`CustomError: Cannot find package '@alias/lib' imported from [...]/ts-node/src/ts-script2.ts`

ts-script2.ts:

```
// import {lib} from "./lib/public-api"; // this works
import {lib} from "@alias/lib";          // this doesn't

console.log(lib('TODO: MAKE THIS WORK'));
```

The `-r tsconfig-paths/register` is supposed to load paths for ts-node, but I'm guessing it conflicts with `--esm` flag? Please help, I spent so much time on this :(

Comment: Were unable to solve this, worked around this by using tsc && tsc-alias instead of ts-node